# Need to make phone field mandatory while installing package from AppExchange

Tags: appexchange

[image: How to make Phone field required while installing package from AppExchange]

When we install the package from app exchange, on Confirm Installation Details page it asks for 
First Name 
Last Name
Company Name
Email
Phone
Country & State

On this page, can we make Phone field as mandatory? Currently, First Name, Last Name, Email, Company are mandatory.